# How to prevent cramp when longboarding?

Tags: longboarding

I have been riding a longboard from time to time and I find that afterwards I often get cramp in my right thigh (my front foot on the deck) I think this is due to misplacement of my body of some kind... is their a way that I can prevent this? maybe by the way I distribute my weight on the leg or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its truly a cramp, then the issue is probably not related to the way you're standing on the board.

Cramps are often caused by:

- dehydration
- performing a foreign activity
- muscle fatigue
- poor conditioning
- etc

Your best bet is to increase your water intake and continue boarding. If after a few weeks the cramps persist, then you may need to see a doctor as it could be something more serious.

Comment: Whats the worst case senario?

Comment: btw I think you were right with the point you made about foreign activity if im work a muscle I haven't done for a while that could cause it couldn't it, my only concern is that I ride a normal skateboard and the motions are pretty similar for a longboard.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is I make sure my peddling motion is one fluid motion and I avoid stomping my foot or heel on the ground to reduce shock. You can take ibuprofen, ice your ankles, elevate your ankles and also wear high top footwear with cushioning, this will give your ankles added support and make pushing and balancing less strenuous on your tendons and heels